# Rails 3 Active Record Fetch associated model based on scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been struggling with this for a whole day now.

Here is what I have. A `User` model and an `Address` model. `User` `has_many :addresses` and `Adddress` `belongs_to :user`.

Now I want to search for users whose email contains a give term, or one of the users's addresses contains that term. So lets say the term is 'jap', any `User` whose `email like '%jap%'` or any user whose any address city or address_line is `like '%jap%'` should be returned.

I can get the Users with a simple join like this

```
users = User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON users.id=addresses.user_id').where('users.email like '%jap%' OR addresses.city like '%jap%' OR addresses.address_line like '%jap%')
```

This gives me the desired users. What I want is that with the returned user I also want those addresses that matched the criteria.

If after the above I do

```
users.first.addresses
```

It will give me all of the that user's addresses. I know I can by doing another query on that user's addresses like this

```
users.first.addresses.where( addresses.city like '%jap%' OR addresses.address_line like '%jap%')
```

But that isnt how it should work. I have tried includes and googled about it but havn't found a solution yet. Any one ever came across this ???

**Edit#1**: there are many similar solutions with 2 queries, What I am after is a single query solution, because to me it doesn't make sense to apply the same conditions on addresses twice.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a named scope on the address model similar to the following ?

```
named_scope :city_or_line_like, lambda { |str| {
    :conditions => ['conditions here']
}}
```

That way you could do `users.first.addresses.city_or_line_like('arg')`?

Comment: that is pretty much the same as above, I have done this. but with this as well I have go run two querries. something like this
`users = User.user_or_address_like('arg')`
and then
`users.first.addresses.city_or_line_like('arg')`

Comment: What I really want is one querry that matches and also brings back the matching addresses for that user